# Layer selection is ignored using terra::as.polygons

Tags: r

I am using terra version 1.7-29 (previously had the same issue with 1.6-17).

## My Data

I have a two-layer raster dataset ([download it here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1377-b4WeaJVLhUe3DfU9Qzjdhmck91vW/view?usp=sharing)):

```
prediction <- terra::rast('path/to/raster.tif')
names(prediction) <- c('prediction', 'validation')
```

It looks like this:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 202, 294, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 2, 2  (x, y)
extent      : 1978598, 1979186, 889666, 890070  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North (EPSG:3413) 
source      : 000.tif 
names       : prediction, validation
```

[image: The original raster dataset]

## The Problem

I would like to create a vector polygon dataset from the 2nd layer, 'validation', but `as.polygons()` seems to be working from the 1st layer, 'prediction'.

```
val_poly <- as.polygons(subset(prediction, 'validation'))
plot(val_poly)
```

[image: Why didn't the polygon get made from the 'validation' layer? This looks more like prediction > 0.5.]

## Other things I've tried

I have also tried subsetting the validation layer first and then providing that to `as.polygons()` (allowing me to check that the subset is working as expected) but it made no difference in the polygon output.

```
val_layer <- subset(prediction, 'validation')
val_poly <- as.polygons(val_layer)

subset(prediction, 'validation')
plot(subset(prediction, 'validation'))
```

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 202, 294, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 2, 2  (x, y)
extent      : 1978598, 1979186, 889666, 890070  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North (EPSG:3413) 
source      : 000.tif 
name        : validation
```

[image: This is the right layer]

## It's Not Reproducible

*(with a handmade SpatRaster, at least)*

When I make a 2-layer SpatRaster by hand and convert the 2nd layer to polygon, it works as expected. This has me considering two options:

1. There may be an issue with my dataset, or
2. there is something going wrong related to how terra handles files on disk (but this is way outside of my coding knowledge comfort-zone).

```
r1 <- rast(ncol=4, nrow=4)
names(r1) <- c('r1')
r2 <- deepcopy(r1)
names(r2) <- c('r2')
set.seed(0)
values(r1) <- c(0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 1, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0)
set.seed(1)
values(r2) <- c(0, 0, 0, 1,
                0, 0, 1, 1,
                0, 0, 1, 1,
                0, 0, 0, 0)
r <- c(r1, r2)
plot(r)
```

[image: The test dataset]

```
test <- as.polygons(r[['r2']])
plot(test)
```

[image]

Comment: What you show is inconsistent. Your SpatRaster "prediction" has two layers, their names are 000_1 and 000_2; and yet you do `subset(prediction, 'validation')`. It is clear that the subsetting goes wrong. Otherwise `as.polygons` would not have the data from the first layer. (note that, by default, the values are rounded --- although the manual says that they are truncated).  You are using an older version of terra (but not showing which. Please update to the current CRAN or development version. It would be useful if you made your file (000.tif) available.

Comment: @RobertHijmans I have edited the question to provide the additional information you requested. This edit also fixes the inconsistency in layer names (I got a little carried away trying to distill a minimal reproducible example, I guess). Unfortunately, updating to the current CRAN version did not change the behavior.

Comment: Thank you, and I stand corrected. This was a bug, not related to subsetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works with terra 1.7-32 (currently the development version); but with the current CRAN version there is an issue that needs a simple work-around.

```
library(terra)
# terra 1.7.29

x <- rast("000.tif")
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 202, 294, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 2, 2  (x, y)
#extent      : 1978598, 1979186, 889666, 890070  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North (EPSG:3413) 
#source      : 000.tif 
#names       : 000_1, 000_2 

x2 <- x[[2]] 
#x2 <- x[["000_2"]]
#x2 <- subset(x, "000_2")

## Work around for current version
x2 <- x2 * 1

p <- as.polygons(x2)
plot(x2); lines(p)
```

[image]
You probably want a polygon for the cell values that are one, but not for the cells that are zero. In that case, you can do

```
x2 <- subst(x2, 0, NA)
p <- as.polygons(x2)
```

The problem is related to this being a file with a particular data type. That is why you could not reproduce it with a SpatRaster that has values in memory. Thank you for revealing this bug!

The development version is available from

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

Comment: FYI I just downloaded the dev version to play around with it and I see the same bug - I'm not entirely sure if you were saying that the issue has already been fixed in the dev version or not, but I figured I would add that in case it is news. However, reclassifying the values seems to also operate as a workaround, which in this case is something I need to do anyway.